# Referencing runtime generated pickers

Tags: appcelerator

I have a simple view:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="window1">
    <Picker  id="picker1" top="0">
    <View id="view1" top="40" />
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

And in the controller i am adding pickerRows to picker1. I can make the selected value of that picker1 visible with

```
Ti.API.info($.picker1.getSelectedRow(0).title);
```

I am also adding (a variable number of) pickers to the view:

```
var data = []; 
data[1]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'1'});
data[2]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'2'});
data[3]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'3'});
data[4]=Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:'4'});

nTop = 80
for (i = 1; i < nNoOfPickers; i++) { 
 picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({top: nTop+10 });
 i++;
 picker.add(data);
 $.view1.add(picker);
 nTop = nTop + 40; 
};
```

My issue now is: how do i get the selected value from one of those generated pickers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ***change*** event listener on every picker to get the values of selected row like this:

```
for (i = 1; i < nNoOfPickers; i++) { 
     picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({top: nTop+10 });
     picker.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        Ti.API.info(e.source.getSelectedRow());
    });
     i++;
     picker.add(data);
     $.view1.add(picker);
     nTop = nTop + 40; 
    };
```

However there are lot of things in your code that you would want to improve, but I have only provided you the answer you are looking for. Hope it helps!

Comment: tnx. i'll give that i try. (i left out quite some code from the program that i am working on. i now notice eg the i++ which looks rather strange indeed! )

Comment: Yes, that's why I copied your code and changed what's needed only. I like to point that if you want to access the run-time pickers, then you can save them in an array or dictionary as per your requirements and you can then access their all properties and methods (P&M). The answer I gave shows only how to access runtime pickers' P&M, but you might need to access some other things also.